# Spring Vaadin theme

Tags: java, spring, maven, vaadin

Hi there I am creating a webapp for college using spring boot and vaadin. All I want to do is change is the background colour. By adding src/man/webapp/VAADIN/themes/myTheme

and then I have

myTheme.scss

```
@import "../valo/valo";

@mixin myTheme {
  @include valo;

}
```

I have also trie valo.scss

styles.scss

```
@import "mytheme.scss";


.mytheme {
  @include mytheme;
}
```

I then call the `@theme` in my ui but i am getting a compilation error, I have tried every which way to go about this.

The valo folder seems to be empty

stack trace

```
INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:8.0.5:compile-theme (default) @ book-reviews ---
[INFO] Updating theme VAADIN/themes/myTheme
[ERROR] Apr 23, 2017 7:14:39 PM com.vaadin.sass.internal.handler.SCSSErrorHandler severe
[ERROR] SEVERE: Mixin Definition: mytheme not found
[ERROR] Compiling theme "VAADIN/themes/myTheme" failed
org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommandException: Command [[
/bin/sh -c '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java' '-Xmx512M' '-Xss1024k' 'com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler' '/Users/teamwork/Documents/book-reviews/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/myTheme/styles.scss' '/Users/teamwork/Documents/book-reviews/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/myTheme/styles.css'
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommand.execute(JavaCommand.java:330)
    at com.vaadin.integration.maven.CompileThemeMojo.processTheme(CompileThemeMojo.java:65)
    at com.vaadin.integration.maven.AbstractThemeMojo.doExecute(AbstractThemeMojo.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.208 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-23T19:14:39+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/437M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:8.0.5:compile-theme (default) on project book-reviews: Compiling theme "VAADIN/themes/myTheme" failed: Command [[
[ERROR] /bin/sh -c '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java' '-Xmx512M' '-Xss1024k' 'com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler' '/Users/teamwork/Documents/book-reviews/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/myTheme/styles.scss' '/Users/teamwork/Documents/book-reviews/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/myTheme/styles.css'
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.book-center</groupId>
    <artifactId>book-reviews</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>book-reviews</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                    <noServer>true</noServer>
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                    <hostedWebapp>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</hostedWebapp>
                    <!-- Remove draftCompile when project is ready -->
                    <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                    <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <!--<goal>clean</goal>-->
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


    </build>


</project>
```

Can someone please help my. Im really not enjoying using it. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps my post https://www.sothawo.com/2015/06/custom-theme-for-a-vaadin-spring-boot-application/ can help. Sorry gor this short answer, but I'm in the road using my phone

Comment: I guess src/**main**/webapp is not the problem?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich sorry i misspelled it here but not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to watch the character case in your `styles.scss`. It should be as follows:

```
@import "myTheme.scss";

.myTheme {
  @include myTheme;
}
```

Note the capital "T". Also ensure that your UI class is annotated with:

```
@Theme("myTheme")
```

Also note that you don't need a `valo` folder, nor will one be created or populated within your project. The imported valo SCSS file and included valo mixin are packaged in the `vaadin-themes` jar.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the theme in src/main/resources/VAADIN/themes/yourtheme

regards